# Firestore Query works from console but not from code

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

As you can see below, I'm getting contradicting results. All help is appreciated.

Firebase Console Query

[image]

Firebase Console Query result

[image]

Code

```
        db.collection("Jobs")
                .whereEqualTo("stationA", "Clacton-on-Sea")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            if (!task.getResult().isEmpty()) {
                                Log.d(tag, "Query snapshot not empty, size is " + task.getResult().size());
                            } else {
                                Log.d(tag, "Query snapshot empty");
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d(tag, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Code Logs

[image]

Comment: have you created index for it?

Comment: @RajasekaranM no? please elaborate.

Comment: yes sure, We have to create index if we are using filter in firestore query

Comment: @RajasekaranM how and where?

Comment: do you printed error in log for firestore? if yes ,you can find url for index

Comment: @RajasekaranM I didn't create a log for firestore, if you're referring to Logcat, please tell me the tag if I have not misunderstood.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206980/discussion-between-rajasekaran-m-and-dylan).

Comment: What does an unfiltered query give you? Are you able to get any documents back for any query?  Is your code querying the same database and project as you're using in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this log, and realised my phone was logged out of wifi. I fixed it by logging into wifi, however I have a strong 4g connection that didnt work on any app. I fixed the 4g issue by restarting my phone

```
W/Firestore: (21.3.1) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds

    This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Editing but leaving the below for reference**

In your query, you are looking for a lower case "s" in "Clacton-on-sea" and your database has an upper case "S"

---

This codelab shows you how to [create a Firestore index from an error displayed in Logcat](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firestore-android/#5).

If you ever run a query that doesn't currently have an existing index, a URL will be displayed in Logcat that you can use to generate the new index. This generally needs to be done anytime you run a query that orders data or combines various operators (ex. "==" and "<").

Comment: As far as I can see, the query does have a capital S.  And an index is not required here because it's just a single field filter, which are all indexed automatically.

Comment: Woah...I must be seeing things. Sorry about that.